# CamelCase to snake_case in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, camelcasing

Do you know if it is possible to transform a field content in CamelCase to snake_case ?

Like this:

```
$ SELECT my_other_field FROM my_table;
+-----------------+
| my_other_field  |
+-----------------+
| ThisIsAnExample |
+-----------------+

$ UPDATE my_table SET my_field = ......(my_other_field);

$ SELECT my_field FROM my_table;
+--------------------+
| my_field           |
+--------------------+
| this_is_an_example |
+--------------------+
```

Comment: could you be a little clearer about the use case you imagine.

Comment: string manipulation differs amongst dbms vendors, what dbms is this for? MySQL?

Comment: SQL? Which vendor/version?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?